# Springboot and Transaction

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one method that have a lot of access in my DB (saves something, find another things, update and more)  It`s possible to log how transaction each process are using and trace if that connection have ben being closed or not? 
My DB are Postgresql

Comment: You can always log out what Spring Boot does, particularly the class(es) and/or package(s) you are interested in — `org.springframework.transaction` in your case. Perhaps you also need the SQL statement(s), so depending on the technology you are using you can do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using `@Transactional` — or any of its "flavors".

Let's also say you are using Log4J 1.x (`.properties` configuration), you can place this line:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction = DEBUG
```

...for the appropriate location/appender.

This will log everything that logs out `debug` statements within that package level (and "onwards").

Similarly you can configure Log4J 2.x, Logback, etc.; the point is to configure an appender for the `org.springframework.transaction` package.